# How to reference multiple foreignkeys from a model

Tags: python, django

I would like to reference 2 separate fields from a model into another model. 
From the code below, i have:
First model with the following fields - name, owner and email

In the second model, i would like to use the data from name and owner above in the second model but renamed them org (name form group) and org_owner (owner from group)

i have tried the below code using related_name. But i get thesame value in both fields. That is a get the name field from group in both the org and org_owner field. Not what i want.

```
class group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=False)


class account(models.Model):
    org = models.ForeignKey('group', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='org')
    org_owner = models.ForeignKey('group', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='org_owner')
    account = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)
```

Expected result should be:

account.org = group.name
 account.org_owner = group.owner

Comment: If you want to access `group.name` from account you would do it with `account.org.name` and to get `group.owner` you would use `account.org.owner`.  You do not need to use the same foreignkey twice

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have group owner in the account once you have added the org as a foreign key.
You should remove the line below from account:

```
org_owner = models.ForeignKey('group', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='org_owner')
```

Group name can be accessed as:

```
account.org.owner
```

And group name should be accessible as

```
account.org.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you're trying to do is join account with group using a condition on two fields. I would suggest you search for how to use a foreign key of two fields rather than using two foreign keys. The other popular way of solving this is to give the group model a generated primary key and have a group_id in the account for the relation. You could then remove (org, org_owner) from account if it serves no other purpose.